# Coldfusion File access using UNC path - access denied

Tags: java, coldfusion, unc

```
    <cfdirectory
    action="list"
    directory="\\uncPath\test"
    sort="directory ASC"
    name="resultQry"
    />
```

Result (in CF error object): **access denied (java.io.FilePermission \uncPath\test read) null**

I found this article: http://coldfusion-tip.blogspot.in/2012/02/file-write-operation-on-shared-path-on.html  (from coldfusion-tip.blogspot)

Which mentions that you need to provide the main Coldfusion Service account that's running, a service account that has access to whatever network location you're trying to access. So I did that, I added AD group permissions (which included access to \uncPath\test) to a separate service account, and am using that instead of the default local service account for the CF Application Service.

I verified that the account does indeed have access to this location, by logging into another machine and navigating to the path in Windows.  Wrote a test text file and moved there to verify that I had both read/write access.

I tried my code again (the CFDIRECTORY) call, and it fails with the same error as before.

If I try to access the same path with an absolute path which is the same location as the UNC path, it works just fine

```
    <cfdirectory
    action="list"
    directory="C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\test"
    sort="directory ASC"
    name="resultQry"
    />
```

So CF treats the two references differently it appears.  I'm just trying to figure out how/why it does, and what work-around I can use to get it to function as desired.

I should also mention that IF I set myself (as the CF service account user) with my AD creds,  the UNC path works just fine and can access the UNC(\uncPath\test). So I'm not sure why there's a discrepancy there between myself, and a service account user w/ the same access rights to a UNC location on the network.

Comment: Are you using ColdFusion sandbox security? Perhaps that is tripping your code up.

Comment: Sorry if this is not helpful, I am assuming your UNC is a Windows shared location. Does your CF service account have access to the actual share? I've had a number of problems with this, and 9 times out of 10, it was a problem with my permissions set up on Active Directory.

Comment: I had same issue: unc path worked with cf running under my account and not working when cf ran undere a service account even though I had manually updated the security properties of the directory to give the security account read permissions.  When I checked the remote box I wanted to access I saw that the local administrators account included an AD group that I was a member of but the service account was not.  I made the service account a member of the local admin group in windows and that solved my problems... please note that it may take several minutes for the account change to proagate